# Django static templatetag not displaying SVG

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to use django's `static` templatetag to display an SVG, but it doesn't seem to recognize the SVG as a valid image url. This is what I currently have:

### settings.py

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("images/svg+xml", ".svg", True)
```

### landing.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'images/right-arrow.svg' %}" />
```

At least in my view.py, it recognizes the SVG mimetype:

### views.py

```
print(mimetypes.guess_type(static('images/right-arrow.svg'))) 
  # returns ('images/svg+xml', None)
```

The SVG does display in a non-django page, and it will download the SVG if I try to open the SVG path in a new browser tab.

I'm currently using python 3.4 and django 1.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In `settings.py`, it should be `mimetypes.add_type('image/svg+xml', '.svg', True)`. `image` should be singular.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.I would recommend you to use :
src="{{ STATIC_URL }} images/right-arrow.svg" instead of src="{% static 'images/right-arrow.svg' %}"

svg format might not always identify django's method of obtaining staticfile contents.Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your **settings.py** file.

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svg", True)
mimetypes.add_type("image/svg+xml", ".svgz", True)
```

In your cases you have added **images** in add_type which should be singular (**image**).

Answer (score 0):

You are loading staticfiles and using static?

This is wrong.

Try changing  `{% load staticfiles %} <img src="{% static 'images/right-arrow.svg' %}" />` to
`{% load static %} <img src="{% static 'images/right-arrow.svg' %}" />` and you also need to consider  which app you should find your static files.